# Trying to make a Home Screen in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to React-Native and I am trying to make a Home Page in my app and at the same time declare some components.
Here is the code I tried to implement

```
import React from "react";
import {createAppContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'
import Buttons from "./Buttons.js"
import PlaylistScreen from "./react/screens/PlaylistScreen.js"

// const navigator = createStackNavigator (
//     {   
//         ButtonsScreen: Buttons,
//         Playlist: {
//             screen: Playlist
//           }
//     },
//     {
//         initialRouteName:'ButtonsScreen',
//         defaultNavigationOptions: {
//             title:"App"
//         }
//     }
// );

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


function MyStack() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Buttons"
        headerMode="screen"
        screenOptions={{
          headerTintColor: 'white',
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'tomato' },
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ButtonsScreen"
          component={Buttons}
          options={{
            title: 'Awesome app',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Playlist"
          component={ {screen: PlaylistScreen}}
          options={{
            title: 'My profile',
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }

export default createAppContainer(Stack);
```

However, I have encounterd problems, giving me those errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah0hc.png)

Please help me, I would be very grateful. :)

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reformatted your code by wrapping your stack navigator inside navigation container and exported MyStack component to be like this:

```
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
    function MyStack() {
        return (
         <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Buttons"
            headerMode="screen"
            screenOptions={{
              headerTintColor: 'white',
              headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'tomato' },
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen
              name="ButtonsScreen"
              component={Buttons}
              options={{
                title: 'Awesome app',
              }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Playlist"
              component={ {screen: PlaylistScreen}}
              options={{
                title: 'My profile',
              }}
            />
           </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        );
      }
    
    export default MyStack;
```